# How can I move the panel from the top to the bottom?

Tags: unity, panel, system-tray

I am coming from Windows 8 and want to test new Ubuntu 12.xx.

How can i change the position of the panel from top to bottom?

Comment: You can't, because Unity was designed to be simple and not very customizable. However, recently Unity has added the ability to move the launcher to the bottom, so let's vote on [this ticket for the ability to move the panel as well](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1627394).

Answer (score 11):

(Assuming you're using the Classic desktop) you can just <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-Drag the panels.

If you're using Unity, you can't customise this. If it's something you need, I'd strongly suggest trying the classic desktop.

Answer (score 8):

**Simple answer**: You can't. At least not with Unity.

**More complicated answer**: Unity Desktop(and Gnome Shell) is made to be simple and look the same on every computer. If you want something that is more customisable, try for example KDE or XFCE, which you can install through the software centre. Then you can set the desktop environment you want to use from the login screen.

Comment: lubuntu is at the bottom of the screen by default

Comment: In XFCE (example: Xubuntu) you can customize the position of that panel. In Lubuntu you cant. Pick that mouse!

Comment: Yes you can move the panel in Lubuntu: http://lubuntuhowto.blogspot.com/2017/03/how-to-move-lubuntu-panel-to-top.html

Answer (score 4):

Regarding moving the panel in Unity: comment #2 in [Movement of Unity launcher](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/668415) has this:

> I think the report actually meant that the launcher should be movable
>   to other edges of the screen. I'm afraid that won't work with our
>   broader design goals, so we won't implement that. We want the launcher
>   always close to the Ubuntu button.
>
> status wontfix
>
> Mark

AFAIK, that's how it still is.

Answer (score 3):

"Super+Alt+Right-click" on the top panel and select "properties".

[image]

Choose "Orientation" from it.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that is a unity panel? I can't get mine to popup any menus?

Comment: I'm sorry. This is for Gnome classic. The question hadn't specified unity.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot move the panel from the top to the bottom using the default Unity desktop.

If you install `gnome-shell` from Ubuntu Software Centre and use `gnome classic desktop` (by selecting it from the login menu) then you can move the panel as described in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

- Install CCSM,
- Install Fbpanel,
- Go intoto Startup applications and add Fbpanel to startup,
- Go into CCSM (Compiz Config Settings Manager) and disable the Unity
  plugin,
- Power off your device. Upon restart you should have the Fbpanel as bottom panel

  and no Unity panels.
- Customize Fbpanel, all you need to edit is in this file:

  http://fbpanel.sourceforge.net/configs/default

That's is it!

**Later edit: initially the shutdown restart and lock may not work but
i uploaded my config file on google drive with repaired commands:**

http://www.editmedia.ro/2014/04/move-unity-bar-to-bottom-disable.html

[image: pic]

Comment: fbpanel is now available through apt-get: `sudo apt-get install fbpanel`

Comment: The link : http://www.editmedia.ro/2014/04/move-unity-bar-to-bottom-disable.html is now broken.

Answer (score 1):

Execute this in a terminal (**Unity**):

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to long-term design goals for the default Ubuntu desktop, you can't arrange desktop components like that. However, we have lots of different desktops in Ubuntu that have many different features like that. We have lots of alternative panels, start menus, etc. But the default desktop is not that customizable.