# How to relocate the Unity top panel to the bottom?

Tags: unity, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I move the panel from the top to the bottom?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155319/how-can-i-move-the-panel-from-the-top-to-the-bottom)

How can I relocate the Ubuntu 12.04 task bar (a.k.a. title bar) -- NOT the launcher bar. The task bar is currently at the top of both displays and I want it on the bottom of one. It contains the clock, volume, shutdown menu icon, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you cannot relocate this bar in Unity. It must be at the top of the screen.