# How to move my display screen

Tags: display, screen

Due to some error in the hardware of my display there is a line on top of my screen(Height : 1cm). Therefore I am unable to see all the buttons on the top most positions. Is there any way to move my screen down so that I can see all the buttons?

[image]

Comment: Does this problem (the line at the to of the screen) only happen in Ubuntu, or is it actually a hardware issue ? What graphics card do you have, with what drivers ? Otherwise, check this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/set-xorg-to-use-only-part-of-the-screen.

Answer (score 0):

Under displays in settings, changing the resolution should do the trick, I'm not on Ubuntu at the moment and that's how it works with my TV through HDMI.
This too so you can make it larger

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Since the resolution thing problem only works on TVs

This should help [Moving bar to bottom](https://askubuntu.com/a/155329/650823)

Comment: That still leaves the panel at the very top of the screen.

Comment: You can't do anything with it on unity